# Not able to see Share point add in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-code, sharepoint, visual-studio-2017

I have just started exploring Visual Studio code. I have installed VS 2017 ,  and i want to create a Share point project. But I cannot see Share point Add-In in installed or Online section.

Can any one please help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40032.visual-studio-2017-missing-office-sharepoint-template.aspx) article, this could be your problem:

> This issue occurs because of the Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017 is not installed.

You would have to add the extension using the Visual Studio installer.